# Magento get recently viewed product Customer wise

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i want to get recently viewed product customer wise so that if customer can come to the website next time and login than, he can find last seen products

please help me

thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that Magento already does this in the block Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed.

This can be added to the home page and uses the template app\design\frontend\base\default\template\reports\home_product_viewed.phtml

The xml layout for the home page "cms_index_index" and the account homepage "customer_account_index" should look something like:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">   
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block> 
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>

<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">   
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block> 
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Comment: which page are you wanting to display it? if it is a cms page you can add it via the admin section under the design tab

Comment: i want to display it in account dashboard and home page

Comment: I have edited the xml to match the customer account and home page.